# Error importing custom python package while using Thonny debug

Tags: python, debugging, thonny

I am learning to import packages in python and facing issue in importing custom packages while debugging code in Thonny IDE.
The issue does not come if I simply run the program.

My relative directory structure is

Compilation\Scripts\tesing_pkg_import.py

Contents of tesing_pkg_import.py is

```
import pandas as pd
def tes_func():
    #Checking for same column name in a single dataframe
    testDpCol = [ (11, 'jack', 34, 'Sydney', 5) ]
    testDfObj = pd.DataFrame(testDpCol, columns=['ID', 'Name', 'Age', 'Name', 'Experience'])
    print(testDfObj.head())
```

Then in Compilation folder I have tesing_pkg_import_main.py content of which are

```
import Scripts.tesing_pkg_import as test
test.tes_func()
```

I have verified

1. That my parent path is present in syspath
2. Program is running successfully
3. Issue comes only when I start debugger in Thonny
4. **init**.py file is present in Compilation\Scripts\ folder

The issue logs are printed as follow :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\***Masked Manually*****\Compilation\tesing_pkg_import_main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Scripts.tesing_pkg_import as test
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 851, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 988, in get_code
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like someone else also faced this issue and raised on github.

Link is to issue is
https://github.com/thonny/thonny/issues/1920

The solution seems to work for me also, fast debug is working which shift-F5 but normal debug is not working which Ctrl-F5.

Anyone who needs help with this can watch the issue on git hub link I have mentioned.